# PHP session starts but does not keeps values

Tags: php, session-variables

I have the following code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
session_start();
set_include_path('../include');
if(isset($_GET["lang"])
    && $_GET["lang"] != $_SESSION["lang"]
    && ($_GET["lang"] == 'en' || $_GET["lang"] =='pt')){
$_SESSION["lang"]= $_GET["lang"];
setcookie("lang", $_GET["lang"]);
}
if(!isset($_SESSION["lang"])){
    if(isset($_COOKIE["lang"])){
    echo $_SESSION["lang"] == $_COOKIE["lang"];
    } else {
        switch(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2)){
        case 'pt': $_SESSION["lang"] = "pt";setcookie("lang", $_SESSION["lang"]); break;
        default: $_SESSION["lang"] = "en";setcookie("lang", $_SESSION["lang"]);
        }

    }
}
print_r($_SESSION);print_r($_GET);print_r($_COOKIE);
require('lang/'.$_SESSION["lang"].'.php');
?>
```

But for some reason the $_SESSION variables do not retain values. The output is the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: lang in /home/claudio/public_html/index.php
>   on line 13 Array ( ) Array ( [get] => get ) Array ( [lang] => en
>   [PHPSESSID] => c92d58e58508gvjf2urfmr9uh3 ) Notice: Undefined index:
>   lang in /home/claudio/public_html/index.php on line 23
>
> Warning: require(lang/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/claudio/public_html/index.php on line 23
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'lang/.php'
>   (include_path='../include') in /home/claudio/public_html/index.php on
>   line 23

If i do `echo session_start();` it returns 1, so what can be the problem with the session?

Comment: Try `echo $_SESSION["lang"] = $_COOKIE["lang"];`. Your are comparing the values and not assigning in your code.

Comment: Btw, consider refactoring your logic because it is over complicated / too many nested `if`s and boolean messes.

Comment: @moonwave99 Can you give an example of how can i check if lang cookie and session is set, and also verify if there are any prompt to change the lang in GET? It was the smallest thing i could do in 10 minutes :(

Comment: @Claudiop first of all, I would go with an object wrapping all the logic inside a `getLocale()` method, which handle all the logic. Then I would just check if the session / req language is `in_array( $yourLanguagesHere )`, so the app would be scalable and not tied just to english and portuguese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `$_GET["lang"]` and `$_SESSION["lang"]` are not set and `$_COOKIE["lang"]` is set, the only thing executed would be:

```
echo $_SESSION["lang"] == $_COOKIE["lang"]; //maybe this should be a '='?
```

If this is not the case, maybe you should check if the session save path in /var/php_sessions is writable by the web server.

Comment: Thats right. Sorry for being so distracted. I took some minutes looking for such errors, but unfortunately  i found nothing...

Comment: Yes, that solved. It was my distraction to leave that "==". As the code already worked before (without cookie set), i discarded some verifications. Thanks a lot :)